# Nesting inside Link from Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I am trying to nest `Badge` inside the `Link`. I tried to wrap it into `<a>` tag. It solved few errors but I am still getting the following one:

[image]

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Menu, Badge } from 'antd';
import { ShoppingCartOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const { Item } = Menu;

const Header = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('home');

  const cart = [1, 2, 3];

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.key);
  };

  return (
    <Menu onClick={handleClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal">
      <Item key="cart" icon={<ShoppingCartOutlined />}>
        <Link href="/cart">
          <a>
            <Badge count={cart.length} offset={[9, 0]}>
              Cart
            </Badge>
          </a>
        </Link>
      </Item>
    </Menu>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Here is a possible solution but I am still getting the same error.

```
const MyBadge = React.forwardRef(({ href }, ref) => {
    return (
      <a href={href} ref={ref}>
        <Badge count={cart.length} offset={[9, 0]}>
          Cart
        </Badge>
      </a>
    );
  });

<Item key="cart" icon={<ShoppingCartOutlined />}>
  <Link href="/cart" passHref>
    <MyBadge />
  </Link>
</Item>;
```

Comment: You can try this https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-function-component

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunatly it does not work

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

You'll need to use `<Link>` inside the badge.

```js
<Badge count={cart.length} offset={[9, 0]}>
  <Link href="/cart">
    <a>Cart</a>
  </Link>
</Badge>
```

Reference - [Badge - Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/badge/#)

---

You need to use `passHref` while using components within `<Link>`

```js
<Link href="/cart" passHref={true}>
  <Badge as="a" count={cart.length} offset={[9, 0]}>
    Cart
  </Badge>
</Link>
```

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunatly it does not work

Comment: unfortunately no difference

Comment: That is quite weird

Comment: I am puzzled as well

Comment: I gave it a try. It works. Using `Link` inside `Badge`.

Comment: here is my code https://github.com/forza11879/next-e-commerce/blob/main/components/nav/Header.jsx#L52